# Gojs draw templateLinks depending on nodeTemplateMap

Tags: javascript, flowchart, gojs

I would like to set different offsets of linkTemplate depending of the nodetemplate type.

Actually I have only one linkTemplate

```
dia.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    // { routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes },  // link route should avoid nodes
    $(go.Shape, { stroke: 'gray', height: 12 }),
    $(go.TextBlock, 'fiber_manual_record', { font: '20pt Material Icons', stroke: 'gray' },
      {
        segmentIndex: 0, segmentOffset: new go.Point(-9, 8),
        segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientAlong
      }),
    $(go.TextBlock, 'fiber_manual_record', { font: '15pt Material Icons', stroke: 'gray' },
      {
        segmentIndex: -1, segmentOffset: new go.Point(-1, 8),
        segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientAlong
      })
  );
```

but I have two nodeTemplateMap every one have a different shape.

My problem is that links don't starts on the same level depending on which node is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Binding to your link template that determines the **Link.fromShortLength** or **Link.toShortLength** depending on the kind of node it is.  Something like:

```
$(go.Link,
  new go.Binding("fromShortLength", "fromNode",
    node => node.category === "A" ? 10 : 20),
  . . .
)
```

Obviously you need to decide how to use the node to determine the value of **Link.fromShortLength** to use.